# AngularJS ng-include issue

Tags: angularjs

I had following html code,

**index.html**

```
<li class = "list-group-item" style="margin:50px;" ng-repeat="product in store.products">
      <h3>
              {{product.name}}
<em class="pull-right">{{product.price | currency}}   </em>
      </h3>
</li>
```

In order to get to know the directive `ng-include`,I added another html in the same directory of `index.html`.

**product-title.html**

```
{{product.name}}
<em class="pull-right">{{product.price | currency}}   </em>
```

And I changed the `index.html` to,

```
<h3 ng-include="'product-title.html'">
</h3>
```

But when I run the index,html, I am not getting the **h3** details,

Please help me to find the mistake.

My Controller:

```
var app = angular.module("store", []);
    app.controller('StoreController', function () {
        this.products = gems;
    });



var gems = [
        {
            name: 'Product1',
            price: '2',
            description: 'Bla bla bla',
            images: [...],
            reviews: [...]
        },
{ .....}
];
```

**Browser Error:**

```
Error: Failed to execute 'send' on 'XMLHttpRequest': Failed to load 'file:///D:/Angular%20JS/Source%20Codes/product-title.html'.
at Error (native)
    at file:///D:/Angular%20JS/Source%20Codes/angular.min.js:79:137
    at s (file:///D:/Angular%20JS/Source%20Codes/angular.min.js:74:109)
    at f (file:///D:/Angular%20JS/Source%20Codes/angular.min.js:71:429)
    at L (file:///D:/Angular%20JS/Source%20Codes/angular.min.js:100:187)
    at L (file:///D:/Angular%20JS/Source%20Codes/angular.min.js:100:187)
    at file:///D:/Angular%20JS/Source%20Codes/angular.min.js:101:350
    at k.$eval (file:///D:/Angular%20JS/Source%20Codes/angular.min.js:112:68)
    at k.$digest (file:///D:/Angular%20JS/Source%20Codes/angular.min.js:109:147)
    at k.$apply (file:///D:/Angular%20JS/Source%20Codes/angular.min.js:112:398) angular.min.js:92
(anonymous function) angular.min.js:92
(anonymous function) angular.min.js:68
L angular.min.js:100
L angular.min.js:100
(anonymous function) angular.min.js:101
k.$eval angular.min.js:112
k.$digest angular.min.js:109
k.$apply angular.min.js:112
(anonymous function) angular.min.js:18
d angular.min.js:35
c angular.min.js:18
fc angular.min.js:18
Xc angular.min.js:17
(anonymous function) angular.min.js:214
a angular.min.js:145
(anonymous function) angular.min.js:31
r angular.min.js:7
c
```

Comment: look like empty store.products, can you show your controller ?

Comment: See browser console if there are 404 errors related to partial template loading.

Comment: Yes I do have an error "Failed to execute 'send'", please see updated question.

Comment: It would suggest to use [`yeoman`](http://yeoman.io) for development of projects using angularJs as it takes care making things like testing the app, starting a server, bootstraping etc

Comment: Thanks. But what should I do to host my web files?, I used the command npm install -g yo and installed successfully. What next. no IDE?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should not be loading `index.html` from `file:///...`. Most browsers will have issues loading  data from `file` URLs, because it triggers cross site scripting protection. Instead, host your directory on a local webserver like LAMP or nodeJs, so your files are coming from `http://localhost/....`

Comment: Either use https://github.com/nodeapps/http-server or use `yeoman` to scaffold your angular application, which will configure a `grunt serve` task for you.

Answer (score 0):

Another way to solve the issue is to create the website using [Microsoft Visual Studio Express for Web](https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/products/visual-studio-express-vs.aspx). (This version is for free).
Once you run your website you will get `http://localhost/....`

Answer (score 0):

I had same issue while running through "file://....".
If you are using Mac or Linux, run your app with python simplehttpserver without installing anything.

`1. cd [your-project-dir]
 2. python -m SimpleHTTPServer`

Your app will run on http://localhost:8000/